# jQuery content slider needed to combine with my menu. Please

Tags: jquery, slide

Can someone please help me. I have got a lava lamp style menu. I really like to see my articles slide like an app, something like a image slider. 
I have made 3 (identical) articles. I really really really hope someone can help me to make them slide.

I have tried something myself but got stucked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".aanbod").on("click", function () {
        $("#slide1").animate({ 'left': 0}, 600);
        $("#slide2").animate({ 'left': 375}, 600);
        $("#slide3").animate({ 'left': 375}, 0);
    });

    $(".vraag").on("click", function () {
        $("#slide2").animate({ 'left': 0}, 600);
        $("#slide1").animate({ 'left': -375}, 600);
        $("#slide3").animate({ 'left': 375}, 600);
    });

    $(".advertenties").on("click", function () {
        $("#slide1").animate({ 'left': 0}, 600);
        $("#slide2").animate({ 'left': -375}, 600);
        $("#slide3").animate({ 'left': 0}, 600);
    });
});
```

> My tried code in codepen
>  
>   http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BcuoE

Answer (score 0):

You should put `#slide1`, `#slide2` and `#slide3` in one `div`. And only animate this one `div`.

Something like this, when `#slide1`, `#slide2` and `#slide3` are in a div called `#mainslide`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".aanbod").on("click", function () {
        $("#mainslide").animate({ 'left': 0}, 600);
    });

    $(".vraag").on("click", function () {
        $("#mainslide").animate({ 'left': -375}, 600);
    });

    $(".advertenties").on("click", function () {
         $("#mainslide").animate({ 'left': -750}, 600);
    });
});
```